# jQuery Mobile, Select not showing selected option until clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add `<options>` to several `<select>` dinamically via ajax, when I add them directly in the HTML works fine, but when I load them in AJAX they will not show the selected option until the `<select>` element is clicked.

I've tried to `.trigger('create')` on all elements and even `.enhanceWithin()` but to no avail.

This jsfiddle shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3c01g6e2/1/

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [demo page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) (also see [documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)):

> If you manipulate a select via JavaScript, you must call the refresh
>   method on it to update the visual styling. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> var myselect = $("select#foo"); 
> myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
> myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
> ```

If you add `$("select").selectmenu("refresh");` to the end of your fiddle, it updates correctly. [(Updated Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3c01g6e2/3/)